# Turning recursive node traversal into iterative node traversal

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom, recursion, iteration

I have a recursive algorithm for traversing nodes in a document tree in [tree order](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-dom-20110915/#concept-tree-order)

How would this be made iterative? [My attempt at making it iterative completely failed](https://gist.github.com/1473536#file_iterate_walk.js)

```
function recursivelyWalk(nodes, cb) {
    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        var node = nodes[i],
            ret = cb(node)

        if (ret) {
            return ret
        }

        if (node.childNodes.length) {
            var ret = recursivelyWalk(node.childNodes, cb)
            if (ret) {
                return ret
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For iterative way you can use Q.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri might mean [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)). What is the reason you're trying to avoid recursion here?

Comment: Q is queue I thought it's obvious.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, writing out "queue" is even more obvious.

Comment: @Jordan one avoids recursion due to lack of tail call optimisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about concatenating the child nodes if there are any, and using a `while(nodes.length)` loop? Basically, keep adding new nodes to the stack, and keep running the loop (testing one node each time) until the stack is empty: http://jsfiddle.net/gEm77/1/.

```
var z = 0; // my precaution for a while(true) loop

function iterativelyWalk(nodes, cb) {
    nodes = [].slice.call(nodes);

    while(++z < 100 && nodes.length) {
        var node = nodes.shift(),
            ret = cb(node);

        if (ret) {
            return ret;
        }

        if (node.childNodes.length) {
            nodes = [].slice.call(node.childNodes).concat(nodes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work if it was changed to enforce tree order. `nodes = [].slice.call(node.childNodes).concat(nodes)` should preserve tree order

Comment: @Raynos: Good call; edited. The new nodes should indeed be pushed to the beginning of the array due to `.shift()`.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.jslab.dk/articles/non.recursive.preorder.traversal.part3) (linked from [Wikipedia's article on tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Iterative_Traversal)) gives an algorithm in JavaScript for iterative preorder traversal of a DOM tree. To quote:

> ```
> function preorderTraversal(root) {
>   var n = root;
>   while(n) {
>   // If node have already been visited
>     if (n.v) {
>       // Remove mark for visited nodes
>       n.v = false;
>       // Once we reach the root element again traversal
>       // is done and we can break
>       if (n == root)
>         break;
>       if (n.nextSibling)
>         n = n.nextSibling;
>       else
>         n = n.parentNode;
>     }
>     // else this is the first visit to the node
>     else {
>       //
>       // Do something with node here...
>       //
>       // If node has childnodes then we mark this node as
>       // visited as we are sure to be back later
>       if (n.firstChild) {
>         n.v = true;
>         n = n.firstChild;
>       }
>       else if (n.nextSibling)
>         n = n.nextSibling;
>       else
>         n = n.parentNode;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Note the line "`// Do something with node here...`", which is where you can call your callback function.

Check out the full article for more information.

Comment: That's an ugly implementation